# phpMyAdmin "The directory you set for upload work cannot be reached"

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am uploading a 24mb sql file and have been following the instructions to setup an upload dir for phpmyadmin using [$cfg['UploadDir']](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#UploadDir). Unfortunately it is not working.

I have created a folder inside my phpMyAdmin folder called 'upload'.

In my config.inc.php I have put the following:

```
$cfg['UploadDir'] = 'upload';
```

This config was wizard created by PMA.

I have also tried:

```
$cfg['UploadDir'] = './upload';
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '/absolute_php_my_admin_address/upload';
```

I've also tried all those variations with a trailing '/' on the end.

I've found many threads on the web with the exact problem. My upload folder has the same permissions and ownership as the parent PMA directory. I am also not running in Safe mode.

Have you run into this issue and solved it? Running PMA 3.5.2 on Redhat 5.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I know this is old but the google search for that problem points here. So here is the answer:

Debian and Ubuntu limits the access for folders. You must use the phpmyadmin folder for that.

In Ubuntu it is "/etc/phpmyadmin/" (without the quotes).

So the config would be:

```
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '/etc/phpmyadmin/';
```

Comment: @willdanceforfun - any chance this could become the accepted answer? It's worked for Diego and for me... and it's the first hit on Google for this problem.  :-)

Comment: @SteveAlmond  I have yielded to this peer pressure and this is now the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, check the upload_max_filesize in php.ini. By default it is 2M, that means, if you upload a file > 2M, it will fail. (Try to compress the SQL file and upload again.) You can change the upload_max_filesize to a bigger value (< 20M) in php.ini and restart your web server.

And, make sure the UploadDir is writable. In Linux, you can run this command to make a folder writable:
chmod a+w upload

Comment: Thanks for that - I have already changed the upload_max_filesize to 80m and other relevant settings such as max execution time etc. The folder is writable also. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

When on a server, for example, I am using HostGator, I needed to login as the root user using `Putty.exe`. 
Then I had to navigate to this file directory,

```
/usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
```

This line

```
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
```

To

```
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '/home/rootnameofwebsite/public_html/createAFolderHere';
```

That got the folders to sync up ok. 
I had a separate issue where it did not recognize the .dbf file I uploaded. Still trying to figure that one out. 
But I did try a regular .sql file and that showed up in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can put backup files in any location, 
just adjust "php_admin_value open_basedir" directive in apache.conf file, it should be in the same directory as config.inc.php (in Ubuntu at least) or somewhere in apache config dir

Answer (score 1):

Quite an old question but been working on this since morning and none of the solutions worked. But finally and like always t was a really simple solution for me on centOS. Please make sure that your folder name is correct. 
e.g:  "/etc/**phpmyadmin/**" **did not work**

but   "etc/php**MyAdmin/**" **worked fine**

Answer (score 1):

Also, remember to check if your `config.inc.php` file already contains these lines:

```
/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
```

If so, remove them.

Answer (score 0):

The directory you set for upload work cannot be reached.

You have to check the UploadDir directory permission.

1) sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/your upload directory path

Then run with the one that works for you
2) sudo chmod 755 /var/your upload directory path
   sudo chmod 644 /var/your upload directory path
   sudo chmod 600 /var/your upload directory path
   sudo chmod 400 /var/your upload directory path