Quick way to import multiple CSV files to phpMyAdmin?
I have a bit of a arduous task each few days whereby my new CSV files (stored locally and on Google Drive) are used for data for my website tables.
The current task involves TRUNCATEing of 15 tables, and then updating each table with the latest CSV by using the IMPORT and "Choose file" option (skipping row 1).
As I'm repeating the exact same task everytime, I was wondering if there was a way to code this using a SQL or trigger to semi-automate the process?
TIA

This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314271/automate-transfer-of-csv-file-to-mysql

Tried that but couldn't figure it out.

Code used was...TRUNCATE wp_qzjvjkcty3_cskatickerstats
LOAD DATA INFILE 'G:\My Drive\CSKA\CSKAData\wp_qzjvjkcty3_cskatickerstats.csv'
INTO TABLE wp_qzjvjkcty3_cskatickerstats
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;

What error did you get?  Was your command line like: mysql -uUsername -pPassword database_name < infile.sql

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127529/import-data-in-mysql-from-a-csv-file-using-load-data-infile

@BartMcEndree    One or more errors have occurred while processing your request:
The following query has failed: "CREATE EVENT UpdateTables ON SCHEDULE AT '2024-09-20 18:33:44.598000' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO TRUNCATE wp_qzjvjkcty3_cskatickerstats LOAD DATA INFILE 'G:\My Drive\CSKA\CSKAData\wp_qzjvjkcty3_cskatickerstats.csv' INTO TABLE wp_qzjvjkcty3_cskatickerstats FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;"
..... 1/2

@BartMcEndree
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LOAD DATA INFILE 'G:\My Drive\CSKA\CSKAData\wp_qzjvjkcty3_cskatickerstats.csv...' at line 2

Get something simple working first then add on one feature at a time. I suggest you get a simple file imported first. Give this file an 8chr.csv name and no header line that needs to be to ignored. Place the file in the UploadDir so you don't need to specify a drive or path. Don't CREATE EVENT or TRUNCATE yet.

Where do i find UploadDir?

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428625/phpmyadmin-the-directory-you-set-for-upload-work-cannot-be-reached
